# Compiler fails with error cs2007 when executing csc.exe manually

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csc

### First of all what I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to create a simple commandline-tool that should be executed before compilation of a project. Goal is to do some pre-work and then execute the real compilation by calling `csc.exe`.

### What I've got so far:

I've created a minimal project that saves the passed arguments. I had to save the content of the rsp-file too because this temp-file gets destroyed after the process.

**Code**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  // Path to temporary rsp file
  var rsp = args[1].Replace("@", "");
  // All lines from the rsp-file
  var files = File.ReadAllLines(rsp);

  // For testing purposes saving the args and the content of the rsp file
  File.WriteAllText("passedArgs.txt", String.Join(" ", args));
  File.WriteAllText("text.rsp", String.Join(" ", files));
}
```

**Modified the csproj-file**

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <!-- deleted unimportant stuff -->
    <!-- compiler.exe is the compiled tool from the code above -->
    <CscToolPath>$(SolutionDir)</CscToolPath>
    <CscToolExe>compiler.exe</CscToolExe>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Fetched data**

Args: `/noconfig @C:\Users\xx\Source\Repos\xxTest\xxTest\text.rsp`
Rsp-file: `/nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ ... classes etc`

**Last testing step (trouble coming)**
I've opened the console and executed:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319> .\csc.exe /noconfig @C:\Users\xx\Source\Repos\xxTest\xxTest\text.rsp`

### Error

```
fatal error CS2007: Unbekannte Option: '/ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Team        Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset"'
PS C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>
```

It says `unknown option <ruleset>`. But without my tool the project is compiling. What am I doing wrong in here?

Google was no help so far.
Thank you very much

Comment: These are quite similar questions: [Unrecognized option '/ruleset' in VS2015 during building](//stackoverflow.com/q/36030089), [VS2015: warning MSB3884: Could not find rule set file](//stackoverflow.com/q/33637211). Can you see if either of those help?

Comment: You're invoking the `csc` that comes with the .NET Framework itself. It does not support `/ruleset` (AKA Code Analysis/FXCop), only the `csc` that comes with Visual Studio does. On my system, that's `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe` (as opposed to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe`).

Comment: You have at least two versions of the C# compiler on your machine.  One is the legacy one, stored in the c:\windows\microsoft.net subdirectory and stuck at version 4.5.  The other is the new one, based on the Roslyn project and the one that acquired support for code analysis.  It is the one that understands /ruleset.  MSBuild tends to be the right choice but keep in mind that this only ever works on your machine, your user typically doesn't have VS installed.  Or use the Nuget package.

Comment: The users of your command line tool should manually edit their `csproj` to include your `targets` file, in which you can hook to the necessary MSBuild events. ANTLR 4 runtime has all the necessary information you can learn from https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs (ANTLR compiler generates C# source files from a grammar files, and then let C# compiler compiles all source code).